# How to create an APIFunction that takes a list with constraints on the list elements?

Tags: programming, wolfram-cloud, apifunction

This `APIFunction` takes a list as an argument:

```
func = APIFunction[{"x" -> DelimitedSequence["Integer", ","]}, #x^3 &]

func["x" -> Range[4]]
```

What I'd like to be able to do is place a constraint on the elements within the list. For example if I wanted to only have elements greater than or equal to zero this works to throw an error for elements that to do fit the criteria:

```
Interpreter[Restricted["Number", {1, \[Infinity], 1}]][Range[-4, 4]]
```

So therefore I thought this might work:

```
func = APIFunction[{"x" ->DelimitedSequence[Restricted["Integer", {1, \[Infinity], 1}],","]}, #x^3 &]

func["x" -> Range[-4, 4]]
```

but it did not.

Does anyone know how `Restricted` can be combined with `DelimitedSequence` or any way that constraints can be placed on elements in lists/arrays that are used as arguments in an `APIFunction`?

Comment: Mike if you can cross post this on [**Community**](http://community.wolfram.com) I might be able to attract some attention from internal folks. I am curious myself.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I might send it to tech support and post the answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRI tech support advise to use this syntax:

```
func = APIFunction["x" -> 
RepeatingElement[Interpreter[Restricted["Integer", {1,\[Infinity], 1}]]], #x^3 &]
```

[image]